# Nullpointer exception when loading texture in libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I get a nullpointer exception when loading splash.png. It works running on android, but throws an exception when running on the desktop even though the file is in android's asset folder and exists in the desktop's asset folder.

Any ideas what's happening? I did clean, restarted eclipse, re-imported the projects...

[image]

```
public class MainMenuScreen implements Screen {

@Override
public void show() {
    Texture background = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/splash.png"));

    }
```

}

Comment: are you able to load that by using "assets/data/splash.png" as path in above statement

Comment: @user2246120 u have to give full path.what happens in android that when u write Gdx.files.internal it check each and every folder having data, but in dekstopyou need to give path from starting folder. which is what vikalp Jain had told you.

If you want to use your code only then remove data folder from assets and keep it seperate and then your code will run fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work like that, your assets folder is not correctly linked.

Taken from here:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Manual-project-setup#asset-folder-setup

"
-Click the Source tab, click Link Source, Browse, select the "assets" folder from your Android project and click OK.

-Specify "assets" for the folder name and click Finish then OK.

Note: If your desktop and Android projects are in the same parent folder, you can use "PARENT-1-PROJECT_LOC/gamename-android/assets" for the location of the linked assets folder, where "gamename-android" is the name of your Android project. This is better than a hard-coded path if you plan on sharing your projects with others."